# If X is connected, then show that no two points with disjoint open neighborhoods can have a retract of X.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a connected space and  $x_{0} ,  x_{1}  \in X$ be two points of $X$ which
have disjoint open neighbourhoods in $X$.

Show that $A$={ $x_{0},   x_{1}$  } can
never be a retract of X.

We know that

1. the Reverse image of any open set is open under the continuous mapping. But I need a proof process.
2. the image of a connected space under a continuous map is connected
3. And in this question: No continuous and Surjective function can be defined from the connected set $X$ to the connected set $A$.

(Question source: Algebraic Topology A Primer -Satya Deo - Chapter 2 (Section 3) - Exercise 2)

Comment: Hint: the image of a connected space under a continuous map is connected.

Comment: @Alen.SR
Please open your answer further.

Comment: @himanmohammadi If $f : X \to A$ was a retraction then $f(X)$ must be connected since $f$ is continuous, but also $f(X) = A = \{x_0, x_1\}$ since $f$ is a retraction. If $x_0$ and $x_1$ have disjoint open neighborhoods the space $A$ is not connected, so this is impossible.

Comment: @KeeleyHoek Why did you write a comment and not an official answer?

Comment: @PaulFrost I have found that a one or two sentence answer often just gets downvoted. But of course I will do whatever people want. :)

Answer (score 1):

A retract $A$ of a connected space is connected (as a continuous image) and the assumptions imply that $A$ is not connected (being a discrete two point subspace).